# How to find eigenvalues of a 3 by 3 matrix when given one?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that the product of eigenvalues equals the determinant and the sum of eigenvalues equals the trace but is there a different way to find eigenvalues when given one?

Comment: In particular,if your matrix is over $\Bbb{C}$, and $\alpha$ is one  eigenvalue, then its conjugate is also the eigenvalue and using your fact to find the  third eigenvalue

Comment: Yes, just compute the characteristic polynomial. It is a cubic polynomial, which splits as a quadratic polynomial and a linear factor with your given eigenvalue. So you only have to find the roots of the quadratic polynomial.

Comment: Yes, elementary row/column elimination can lead to Jordan normal form.

Comment: @LearningMathematics I think you’re getting things backwards. Any diagonal matrix with completely unrelated complex entries is a counterexample. It’s *real* matrices for which complex eigenvalues are guaranteed to come in conjugate pairs.